# Adding tkinter ScrolledText to a grid

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

So, I have a basic layout that is created with the following code (written here for brevity):

```
class ClientUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init(self, master, client, queue, send_command):
        self.master = master
        self.master.grid()
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)
        self.create_widgets()

        # This is just to figure out what's going on
        pprint(vars(master))
        self.output_panel = master.children['output']

    def create_widgets(self):
        output = ScrolledText(self.master, name="output", state=tk.DISABLED)
        output.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
```

Which I had hoped would add the `ScrolledText` to the grid. This did work when I was using just a `Text` widget.

However, I get a `KeyError` because `output` is not in the children list. Here is the output of the `pprint` statement (again, cut to show pertinent portion):

```
'children': {'34864544': <client.clientui.ClientUI object at 0x000000000213FDA0>,
          '46887376': <tkinter.Frame object at 0x0000000002CB71D0>,
          '46890008': <tkinter.Menu object at 0x0000000002CB7C18>,
          'input': <tkinter.Entry object at 0x0000000002CB76A0>}
```

As you can see, there is a named `input` child that was added in code not shown. However, the `output` named widget doesn't appear to be added. Why does `output.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)` not add it as expected?

Comment: If `self` is a `Frame`, shouldn't you add the widgets to `self` instead of `master`?

Comment: I agree with tobias_k why don't you just do `output = ScrolledText(self, ...` ?

Comment: @tobias_k Despite that being probably a good idea. The question remains that adding a `Text` widget to `self.master` did work. Is there something different about `ScrolledText`? Maybe because it is in a `Frame` itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like creating a [`ScrolledText`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html#module-tkinter.scrolledtext) actually creates a `Frame` wrapping the actual `ScrolledText` widget together with a `ScrollBar`, and the `name` you assign to the `ScrolledText` is not assigned to the `Frame`, but to the wrapped `ScrolledText`.

Thus, `master.children` does indeed not contain a child with name `'output'`, but the `Frame`. The `'output'` widget can then be found among the children of that `Frame`.

```
>>> pprint(master.children)
{'140447721418704': <tkinter.Frame object at 0x7fbc888b6fd0>}
>>> pprint([c.children for c in master.children.values()])
[{'140447721417696': <tkinter.Scrollbar object at 0x7fbc888b6be0>,
  'output': <tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText object at 0x7fbc888b6f98>}]
```

So if you want to get a reference to the `ScrolledText` widget you have to get if from the `Frame`, but instead it might be much easier to just bind it to `self` when you create it, i.e.

```
self.output = ScrolledText(self.master, name="output")
```

This is indeed the same object as the one you would get from the `Frame`'s children:

```
self.output_panel = next(c.children["output"] for c in master.children.values() if "output" in c.children)
print(repr(self.output_panel))
print(self.output_panel is self.output)
```

Output:

```
<tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText object at 0x7f3e02bf6f98>
True
```

Comment: Setting the property `self.output` in the `createWidgets` method causes PyCharm to whine. I am unsure of the reasoning, since self gets passed around anyway. For that receive assigning it to `self.output` was originally avoided. Find that the `ScrolledText` is wrapped in a `Frame` like my comment mentioned makes perfect sense.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel Probably PyCharm is complaining about adding more `self.something` attributes outside of `__init__`, but I guess looking up children by their name is much worse. I suggest that either, you "inline" the content of `create_widgets` into `__init__` or make it return the widgets that were created.